# Store value when use two(even more) for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a dice simulator, which use two for() function to loop.

But I can't store the output. Below is my code.

```
dice <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),1,6)

sim <- matrix() ; sim_mean <- c() ; sim2 <- c()
for ( N in c(20,50,100) ) {
  
  for ( i in 1:10 ) {
    
  sim <- sample(dice , size = N , replace = TRUE)
  
  print(sim)
  
}
  }
```

I want to make a matrix or list to store them, but failed many times.

How can I store the output `sim` ?

Comment: to store the output you should use something like `append` to fill the vectors and for the matrix I would suggest that you create an empty matrix with the corresponding size, e.g. `sim <-- matrix(NA, 3,10)` and store the values inside the inner loop with `matrix[j, i] <- sample(...)` where j is a count variable which you should place in the outer loop

Comment: To add the comment by @JKupzig, currently your loop overwrites `sim` each time instead of adding in the result to your `sim` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `sim` in each loop. You can create a matrix and fill up the individual regions inside the matrix or append the results. Instead of `for` you can use `lapply` and `sapply` to store the result as a list or matrix.

```
dice <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),1,6)

set.seed(42) #To get same samples
sim <- NULL
for ( N in c(20,50,100) ) {
  x <- matrix(0, N, 10)  #Create matrix for all results in this loop
  for ( i in 1:10 ) {
    x[,i] <- sample(dice , size = N , replace = TRUE) #Fill the columns
  }
  sim <- c(sim, list(x)) #Append the results of the N loop as a list
}

set.seed(42)
sim2 <- lapply(c(20,50,100), \(N) {
  sapply(1:10, \(i) {
    sample(dice , size = N , replace = TRUE)
  })
})

identical(sim, sim2)
#[1] TRUE

str(sim)
#List of 3
# $ : num [1:20, 1:10] 1 5 1 1 2 4 2 2 1 4 ...
# $ : num [1:50, 1:10] 6 5 6 4 1 5 4 1 1 1 ...
# $ : num [1:100, 1:10] 3 1 6 3 5 5 2 1 3 4 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my question is why I can't store the values ​​from two loops. Because the loops I set can indeed achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Base R `lapply` function twice to store the result in a dataframe automatically. See below.

```
resample <- function(N, n_resample = 10){
  lapply(1:n_resample, \(x)sample(1:6, size = N, replace = TRUE))
}

repeated_resample <- function(N, n_resample){
  lapply(N, function(x){resample_results(N = x, n_resample = n_resample)})
  }
results <- repeated_resample(N = c(20,50,100), n_resample = 10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but same as above, my question is why I can't store the values ​​from two loops. Because the loops I set can indeed achieve what I want.